# Hot keys in close vote review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, closing, keyboard-shortcuts

When I am in the review queue, if I click to close a question, I have to select an option on a pop up screen, press a button and then again select an option and press a button again for another screen. The thing is almost 90% of the close reasons go as:

> Community specific reason--> missing context/ details

I would suggest for some hot key feature for running through the close options quickly.

Comment: I agree it is a bit annoying but I don't think this is needed. (note moderators are able to edit the list of community-specific close reasons but can't change their locations)

Comment: Somewhat similar feature request on [meta.se]: [Keyboard shortcuts for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242001). (There is also this feature request - but it seems to be a bit different. AFAICT it is asking just for the [existing keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166) to be enabled also in the review queues: [Fully enable keyboard shortcuts in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315782).)

Comment: It should not be *too* easy to review. Reviewing needs be done when one is doing so, alert, deliberately.  One key quickie actions lead to users focused more on speed in reviewing, rather than on quality, and one-key responses make reviewers more susceptible to get in an autopilot trance, reacting, rather than considering, and taking appropriate actions.

Comment: @amWhy Agreed, but the history of software development has told us numerous times that inhibiting UI to make users more alert doesn't work all that well, it just drives people away.

Comment: @DonThousand  If some people are too lazy to review unless they can press one, and only one key!(dang it!), I don't think they should be reviewing in the first place.  You are talking to an exceptionally active reviewer, and it goes pretty quickly, as is.

Comment: And do you realize, @DonThousand, just how many "hot keys" would be required, say, e.g., in the review queue for close votes?  Close or keep open or edit, for close, we'd need a hot key for close for this reason, close for another reason, close for a third reason, close for a fourth reason... ad nausium...

Comment: @amWhy I haven't really thought about how hotkeys would be implemented, to be honest, and I don't really think they would make a difference for me. My point is, the reason you gave for not liking hotkeys is generally not seen as a good SD paradigm.

Comment: @DonThousand But we also don't want to make it too easy for users to make typos and inadvertently click on on action they didn't want to take, or a design allowing bots to easily manipulate review queues.  I'm sure there would be a way to do this, but to save folks time? Likely not.

Comment: @DonThousand I think the review queues design is deliberately intended to have what you're describing as a poor SD paradigm.  The aim is to keep people out of the review queues unless they're willing to spend care and attention on the reviews they do as poor reviews are worse than no reviews.  This might be one of those exceptions that prove the rule :)

Comment: The review system with responsive design has already become much faster than what it used to be. For me on a mobile device this is like an improvement of 5 times (or even more).

Comment: Buraian: could you provide the source of your estimate (90% of all close votes....)?

Comment: I'd say it's anecdotal in the review queue, and from my experience of browsing the site. If there was statistics for why questions are most closed, I'd say it would show that too. What is your experience? @amWhy